# How does this code works?

Tags: python, shared-libraries, ujson

The Python source code of the ujson library is as follows.

```
# encoding: utf-8
# module ujson
# from /home/marty/dj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ujson.so
# by generator 1.136
# no doc
# no imports

# Variables with simple values

__version__ = '1.33'

# functions

def decode(*args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
    """ Converts JSON as string to dict object structure. Use precise_float=True to use high precision float decoder. """
    pass

def dump(*args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
    """ Converts arbitrary object recursively into JSON file. Use ensure_ascii=false to output UTF-8. Pass in double_precision to alter the maximum digit precision of doubles. Set encode_html_chars=True to encode < > & as unicode escape sequences. """
    pass

def dumps(*args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
    """ Converts arbitrary object recursivly into JSON. Use ensure_ascii=false to output UTF-8. Pass in double_precision to alter the maximum digit precision of doubles. Set encode_html_chars=True to encode < > & as unicode escape sequences. """
    pass

def encode(*args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
    """ Converts arbitrary object recursivly into JSON. Use ensure_ascii=false to output UTF-8. Pass in double_precision to alter the maximum digit precision of doubles. Set encode_html_chars=True to encode < > & as unicode escape sequences. """
    pass

def load(*args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
    """ Converts JSON as file to dict object structure. Use precise_float=True to use high precision float decoder. """
    pass

def loads(*args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
    """ Converts JSON as string to dict object structure. Use precise_float=True to use high precision float decoder. """
    pass

# no classes
```

ujson execute any methods just with this code. The external file named `ujson.so` is a [shared library.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29#Shared_libraries)

do the `# from`, `# module`, `# by generator`, `# no doc`, `no imports` comments have any effect on this code (I know `# encoding` specifies the encoding of the file)

> **From pypi** 
> UltraJSON is an ultra fast JSON encoder and decoder written in pure C with bindings for Python 2.5+ and 3.

My questions,

1. How do calling a method (for example `ujson.loads(my_string)`) executes?
2. How is the python method redirected/linked to the shared object?
3. What is this method of Python programming called?

Comment: That file is generated from https://github.com/esnme/ultrajson/blob/master/python/ujson.c

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah! but how the code is linked with the Python code here?

Comment: That's much too broad to be answered here - look at e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/extending/index.html